# How to open a file with a .backup extension in Lubuntu 20.04LTS?

Tags: backup

I noticed that in my home/user folder there is a file called sda6.backup.
It is seen below as the first file on the right in the second row.   
How do I open it? (I have accidentally deleted some files in January and am hopefully that these might be found in this file as it has 11Gb of data.)   
  
Now, right clicking on it only gives me "Other Applications" option under "Open With" sub-menu. Under MIME Type I can see "application/octet-stream" Any ideas? Hope that someone might know the answer.

UPDATE: Running `file sda6.backup` gives the following result:  
    `sda6.backup: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=acf3351d-4362-4f2a-bd35-ad5e4cf4dd35 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (64bit) (large files) (huge files)`

[image]

Comment: Open a terminal, verify that you are in the correct directory, and run `file sda6.backup` and update the question with the result. File-extensions have no special meaning in Linux but the file-program can decode the file-magic.info.

Comment: You can probably mount the file using `mkdir /tmp/budisk ; sudo mount /home/user/sda6.backup /tmp/budisk` and then going to directory `/tmp/budisk` to inspect its contents.

Comment: I have tried this and sudo mount /home/user/sda6.backup /tmp/budisk` gives the following output: `mount /tmp/budisk: special device /home/user/sda6.backup does not exist`.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /home/user/sda6.backup`? Please note that by "user" I mean your local user name. (I think it is something like `mark` in your case.)

Comment: The output is `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 11773411328 Jan  5 23:50 /home/mark/sda6.backup`

Comment: So, you can try `mkdir /tmp/budisk ; sudo mount /home/mark/sda6.backup /tmp/budisk`.